# NSUserDefaults failing and not retrieving data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I really hope this isn't redundant, but I honestly can't find the answer in other SO posts.

In my app delegate I set a value of `0` for key `TopScoreLevel1`. Later in the app I then run this snippet of code:

```
        NSLog(@"This is your new score: %@", newScoreString);
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"xxx" forKey:@"TopScoreLevel1"];
        BOOL fail = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        if (!fail){
            NSLog(@"success.");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"fail.");
        }

        NSString *printRecorded = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"TopScoreLeve1"];
        NSLog(@"Class: User Score. DID USER DEFAULTS SAVE? --> %@", printRecorded);
```

New score prints a value successfully, but my synchronize method fails. I also get a `(null)` value for `printRecorded`. Bizarre. Any ideas?

Comment: this hard-coded string keys can be a hard nut to crack while debugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you’re setting the value, you’re using the key `@"TopScoreLevel1"`. When you’re getting it, you’re using `@"TopScoreLeve1"`—note no L before the 1. Change one of those to match the other and you should see the correct behavior.

Comment: Great! that solved the printing issue, but unfortunately not the problem of the `fail` result I'm getting :(

Comment: Okay, I'm still getting a fail, but the results are correct so I guess I'll just ignore that.

Answer (score 1):

you are saving a object in `NSUserDefaults` and after that you are retrieving a `stringForKey` so first of all use `setString:forKey` and then try it solved your problem or not?

and you are also retrieving the value `@"TopScoreLeve1"` where you are saving value in `@"TopScoreLevel1"` correct it.

Comment: Yes, fixing the typo helped :). But there is no `stringForKey` method for NSUserDefaults.

Comment: okeys sorry `stringForKey:` method is there but `setString:forKey` is not there.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

```
- (BOOL)synchronize
```

Return Value

YES if the data was saved successfully to disk, otherwise NO.

Try:

```
BOOL status = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

if (status == YES){
    NSLog(@"success.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"fail.");
}
```

Negative logic is harder and double negative really hard,thus
`!fail`
it a lot harder to understand than
`status = YES`

But then clarity in code is not everything. :-)